# Show numeric textbox value with leading zeros

Tags: c#

I have 3 text box values as:

```
no of requests = 2
court fee = 60
claim amount = 200
```

My client requirment would like them to show:

```
no of requests = 00002; // 5 characters
court fee = 000006000; // 9 characters
claim amount = 0000020000; // 10 characters
```

I tried this but not getting those values. I dont know where am I going wrong.

```
decimal requests = 0;
decimal CFee = 0;
decimal CLAIMAMT = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    CFee += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CFee"].Value) / 100 * dataGridView1.RowCount;
    CLAIMAMT += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CLAIMAMT"].Value) / 100 ;
    requests = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString());
}

textBox3.Text = CFee.ToString();//court fee
textBox4.Text = CLAIMAMT.ToString();//claim amoiunt
textBox2.Text = requests.ToString();//no
```

Answer (score 8):

Don't use decimal for whole numbers.  Use int for whole numbers and decimal for currency amounts and the like.  If you want leading zeroes then you can do so like this:

```
var str = number.ToString("00000"); // At least five digits with leading zeroes if required.
```

Comment: Nice spot on the int - I assumed it had to accept decimals. Personally I'm not a massive fan of the format strings as they're sometimes a little unclear but that's purely personal preference!

Comment: Alternatively, they could use the `D` format specifier: `ToString("D5")`, `ToString("D9")`, `ToString("D10")` etc (assuming that they switch to using `int` rather than `decimal`). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [String.Format](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

For example, to add zeroes before a number, use **colon separator** `:` and write as many zeroes as you want.

```
String.Format("{0:00000}", 2);          // "00002"
String.Format("{0:D5}", 2);             // "00002"
String.Format("{0:D9}", 6000);          // "000006000"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [PadLeft](http://www.dotnetperls.com/padleft) method. It will append as many of the character you specify to the left of the string until it reaches the length given in the 1st parameter.

```
textBox3.Text = CFee.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
```

Comment: I tried this query very near but not ...exactly what i want.  request satisfied 00001. but CFEE = 00015 and CLAIMAMT = 00100 but i need it like  000001500 and Claimamt like 0000020000

Comment: @preethi there's a PadRight too if that helps. It's quite hard to answer without understanding the format of your numbers

Comment: You are creating two strings when only one is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this;

```
string request = "2";
            while (request.Length < 5)
                request = "0" + request;

            string fee = "60";
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                fee = "0" + fee;
            while (fee.Length < 9)
                fee += "0";

            string claim = "200";
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                claim = "0" + claim;
            while (claim.Length < 10)
                claim += "0";
```

This is exactly what you expect:
Output

"00002"

"000006000"

"0000020000"

Comment: how can i pass values which are in textbox or data gridview

Comment: You mean something like:
string request = textBox1.Text;
            while (request.Length < 5)
                request = "0" + request;
textBox1.Text = request;

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use String.Format() like this?

```
myTextbox.Text = String.Format("{0:000000}", 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ToString` with `D` format specifier:

```
decimal noOfRequests = 2;
decimal courtFee = 60;
decimal claimAmount = 200;

int noOfRequestsInt = Convert.ToInt32(noOfRequests);
int courtFeeInt = Convert.ToInt32(courtFee);
int claimAmountInt = Convert.ToInt32(claimAmount);

string requests = noOfRequestsInt.ToString("D5");   // output: 00002
string fee = courtFeeInt.ToString("D9");            // output: 000000060
string amount = claimAmountInt.ToString("D10");     // output: 0000000200
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#DFormatString

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

Comment: `int CFee = 0;
 int CLAIMAMT = 0;
 int requests = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                CFee += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CFee"].Value) / 100 * dataGridView1.RowCount;
                CLAIMAMT += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CLAIMAMT"].Value) / 100 ;
            }

           string textBox3 = CFee.ToString("d9"); //court fee
           string textBox4 = CLAIMAMT.ToString("D10");//claim   `

Comment: You can convert `decimal` to `int` with `Convert.ToInt32(decimal value)`

Comment: Format specifier was invalid. string textBox3 = CFee.ToString("D9");

Comment: if `CFee` is `decimal` first convert it to `int`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in XAML.
Text="{Binding Path=DailyPushTimeHour, StringFormat={0:00}}"